# Randomly scale and rotate a bunch of graphics to spread around as a background

Tags: adobe-indesign, software-recommendation, resource-recommendations

I would think that this is a common enough request that there is a program / method to achieve this. I'm looking for a way to take a graphic, like a vector of a carrot or something, and multiply it, then randomly scale and rotate each and spread around, as a background. I'm sure you've seen what I'm describing. It's so tedious to do it manually, just wondering if anyone here in the graphic design community has any experience with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to adobe illustrator then you can use the TRANSFORM EACH function which has a random option. Lots of control over how random you want it to be too.

Answer (score 0):

One option in Illustrator is to turn your object in to a symbol and use the Symbol Sprayer Tool then the various symbol manipulation tools to scale, rotate etc.

This took me all af about 2 minutes:

> [image]

Another option, as [Chris says](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/80339/52050), is to use Illustrator's Transform functions.

You can use a Tranform *effect* (not the normal function, but the one in the effects menu), to duplicate your object a number of times:

> [image]

Then add another transform effect:

> [image]

Expand the appearance of the result, ungroup the objects, then select all and use the Transform Each function with "Random" checked:

> [image]